# How to stop Atom from changing != into a different symbol

Tags: atom-editor, ligature

I have started using Atom to make clean screen shots of my code for presentation purposes, primarily because it has the indent guides for clear syntax visibility.

This is the first time I have used a program with a `!=` operator. And Atom keeps changing the `!=` into a weird looking crossed out elongated equal sign. I have looked into the preferences & packages, but I cannot find anything that might control symbols being altered.

Would anyone be able to point me to where this automatic alteration can be turned off?

Comment: Thats just the font. Probably with monospaced chars like [FireCode](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode). Change the font to one that does not have those combined chars.

Comment: The "weird looking crossed out elongated equal sign" means "not equal". Atom is probably changing `!=` for a character universally understandable that takes the same amount of space. I wouldn't be bothered by that, but if you really require to show the actual code, I would look into the font you're using, since some of them have these characters to substitute certain chains of characters. Other examples of such chains that might be replaced can be `===`, `->`, etc...

Comment: Here is a github issue with a [proposed solution](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/issues/633#issuecomment-651898400).

Comment: Thanks heaps for the responses. It is the font, I changed it and that fixed it. But, I am using the font to match an presentation template at this point. The GitHub solution addition to my Stylesheet in Atom worked.